# If it is correct to claim that the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt t}$ is not continuous?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, continuity, laplace-transform

There is "Sufficient Condition Theorem" to test if a function's Laplace transform exists.

**If a function $f$ is
piecewise continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and is of exponential order $\alpha$, then the Laplace transform of $f$ exists
for $s>\alpha$.**

I read a document stating that this sufficient condition may not be necessary, i.e., a function which is not piecewise continuous on $[0,\infty)$ can also have its Laplace transform exist. Then take $f(t)=t^{-\frac12}$ for example.

However, $f(t)$ will have no definition at $t=0$ therefore, I am not completely convinced by the example.

Does it mean that all continous functions have to be defined in a closed domain?

Then what other examples can be more persuasive to the sufficient condition theorem?

Comment: The function $t \mapsto \frac1{\sqrt t}$ is continuous (on its domain), but it is not (piecewise) continuous on $[0, \infty)$ because it is not even defined there. Another instructive example is the characteristic function $\chi_{[0, 1]}$ of the interval $[0, 1]$, which has a discontinuity in $[0, \infty)$ precisely at $x = 1$, but $\mathcal L\{\chi_{[0, 1]}\}$ has domain $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, it is the point. But I am wondering why cannot we find some indisputably discontinous function that has Laplace transform.

Comment: @MathArt He just gave you an example.......

Comment: If $f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt t}$ were defined at $t=0$, would it not be piecewise continuous on $[0, \infty)$?

Comment: Don't get confused on examples, get yourself to understand the definitions. I won't down-vote, but I'm unusually tempted to.

Comment: @MathArt I'm not sure what you're asking for, exactly. Are you looking for an example of a function $f : [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ that is *not* piecewise continuous but for which there is nonetheless an $\alpha$ such that $\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s)$ exists for all $s > \alpha$? If so, what is your (precise) definition of piecewise continuous? If you only allow finitely many discontinuities (as some definitions require), for example, then $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty e^{-n} \chi_{[n, n + 1)}$, $\alpha = 0$, is such an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all comments! Yes, @Anne Bauval, it is nice link where I learned "Piecewise functions must be defined on the endpoints of their subdomains".